# Migrating from Apache SOLR Cloud to Standalone version

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We are now running an Apache Solr cloud cluster and we would like to migrate it to a standalone server.
I don't find any related info so I wonder if it is possible ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: The most direct way would be to reindex your content on a single server instead; I don't think you'll easily be able to do this in any automagic way without exporting from your cloud setup and import in your single core setup.

Answer (score 1):

SolrCloud stores data in Collections and depending on number of shards and replicas, the cores are created accordingly.

Eg. If you have a collection Employee with replication factor 2 and shard 1 then cores will be like Employee_shard1_replica1, Employee_shard1_replica2

But in Standalone solr, data will be stored directly to Cores means Employee will be your core instead of collection.

*If you have single shard then you can try to copy the indexes from any one replica to the core you create. But in case of multiple shards that data will also be devided into multiple cores which you won't be able to merge manually. So, first you have to do shards merging and then you have to do this.*

**All in short, the best way to do this is to copy your configs to the standalone solr and then create and index the individual collections.**

**For indexing, either you can index the data from original source or you can index from the data already indexed in the solrcloud collecitions from DIH.**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you replies. Re indexing seems to be a good solution

Comment: This seems to be rather a comment than an answer